# How can I use an HTML page as an email that reads as such in mail servers exactly as seen on the web?

Tags: html-helper

I prepared an email that would look interesting, and tried to send it by using Safari. The setup did not come out in the emails the way it looks at the web page. In some web clients only the blue background came out, in others there was no background and the three columns were set one after the other, with the center one last. In other words a mess, and I do not know how to remedy it. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Many popular email clients (not including Mail on the Mac) have very poor HTML/CSS renderers.

There's really no substitute for testing how your email renders on a wide range of email clients before sending it out.  A tool like [Litmus](http://litmusapp.com/) can save a great deal of time here.

Or, you can always just send text-only email.